ValueError: Expected each embedding in the embeddings to be a list, got ['Repeated']
I'm trying to create a chat with website streamlit app with Google AI but have faced multiple errors for the same. The latest one being Error Message
and here's the code
import streamlit as st
from langchain_core.messages import AIMessage, HumanMessage
from langchain_community.document_loaders import WebBaseLoader
from langchain.text_splitter import RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter
from langchain_community.vectorstores import Chroma
from langchain_google_genai import GoogleGenerativeAIEmbeddings, ChatGoogleGenerativeAI
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from langchain_core.prompts import ChatPromptTemplate, MessagesPlaceholder
from langchain.chains import create_history_aware_retriever

load_dotenv()

def get_response(user_input):
    return "I don't know"

def get_vectorstore_from_url(url):
    # getting the text in document format
    loader = WebBaseLoader(url)
    document = loader.load()

    # split the documents into chunks
    text_splitter=RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter()
    document_chunks = text_splitter.split_documents(document)

    # create a vector store from the chunks
    vector_store = Chroma.from_documents(document_chunks, GoogleGenerativeAIEmbeddings(model = "models/embedding-001"))
    return vector_store


def get_context_retriever_chain(vector_store):
    llm = ChatGoogleGenerativeAI(model = "gemini-pro")

    retriever = vector_store.as_retriever()         # langchain function to retrieve relevant text to a query

    prompt = ChatPromptTemplate.from_messages([         # prompt in the form of a list of messages
        MessagesPlaceholder(variable_name="chat_history"),      # replaces with the chat_history, if it exists
        ("user", "{input}"),
        ("user", "Given the above conversation, generate a search query to look up in order to get information relevant to the conversation")
    ])

    retriever_chain = create_history_aware_retriever(llm, retriever, prompt)

    return retriever_chain

# App configuration
st.set_page_config(page_title="Chat with Websites", page_icon='️')
st.title("Chat with Websites")

# By default, streamlit runs our code every time any event occurs on the app and 
# the history variable gets reinitialised each time and new messages are appended above
# to overcome this the following code block has been used

if "chat_history" not in st.session_state:
    st.session_state.chat_history= [
        AIMessage(content="Hello, I am a bot. How can I help you today?")
    ]

# Sidebar
with st.sidebar:
    st.header("Settings")
    website_url= st.text_input("Website URL")
    
if website_url is None or website_url == "":
    st.info("Please enter a website url")

else:

    vector_store = get_vectorstore_from_url(website_url)

    retriever_chain= get_context_retriever_chain(vector_store)

    # User input
    user_query=st.chat_input("Type your message here...")
    if user_query is not None and user_query !="":
        response=get_response(user_query)
        st.session_state.chat_history.append(HumanMessage(content=user_query))
        st.session_state.chat_history.append(AIMessage(content=response))

        retrieved_documents = retriever_chain.invoke({
            "chat_history": st.session_state.chat_history,
            "input": user_query
        })
        st.write(retrieved_documents)

    # Conversation
    for message in st.session_state.chat_history:
        if isinstance(message, AIMessage):
            with st.chat_message("AI"):
                st.write(message.content)
        elif isinstance(message, HumanMessage):
            with st.chat_message("Human"):
                st.write(message.content)



I have tried to use different models offered by Gemini but still nothing. I'm expecting an output like this Ideal Output.
Please help me out!

Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.
